# Deploying a silverlight site

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have just tried to deploy my silverlight 4 site and ran across a problem.
I keep all of my styles etc. in a resource file and reference them like this:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Templates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

After deploying my website, my listbox (which has an overriden item template which i store in my templates.xaml) looked empty. However i know that i should see three items in my listbox, and i am able select three lines in the listbox they are just all empty. The problem seems to be that nothing gets drawn in the listbox items because i can not get to the resource file to get my style.
I have tried making the resource files embeded resources but no help.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the Templates.xaml file is part of your xap file.

To do that make sure the "Build Action" (in the properties of the Templates.xaml file) is set to "Resource"